# Color Transition of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to make a `JButton` go through a color transition and so i added an action listener to it that does the following:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Color c = new Color((int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256));
    Color cc = v.get(1).getBackground();
    //(...) The r, rr, b, bb, g, gg are just the components of the colors c and cc
    boolean boo = true;
    while(boo){
        if(r < rr){
            r++;
        }
        if(b < bb){
            b++;
        }
        if(g < gg){
            g++;
        }
        if(r == rr && b == bb && g == gg){
            boo = false;
        }
        Color color = new Color(r, b, g);
        v.get(1).setBackground(color);
        v.get(0).setBackground(color);
        frame.repaint();
        frame.revalidate();
    }
```

but this doesn't make the transition happen, it really just changes the color of the Button. What am I missing here?

Comment: *"What am I missing here?"* Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix (a `Timer`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use another Thread to do this logic and start that thread when the action occurs. Long actions block the thread responsible for graphical changes.

So, your problem is that you intend every graphical change to be done real-time, but instead of working asynchronously with a separate thread, you work synchronously, releasing the EDT when the event function completed.